# Pascal: Got to subtract 1 from length to get right size

Tags: for-loop, pascal

I've got a piece of code like this:

```
for I := 0 to Self.EventQueue.Count do
    Dispose(Self.EventQueue[I]);
```

It bugs out when the Count is 0, because it tries to `Dispose` a nonexisting element. When I change it to

```
for I := 0 to Self.EventQueue.Count-1 do
    Dispose(Self.EventQueue[I]);
```

All works fine. Is there any elegant way to get around this or is this common practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely normal behavior, and is documented in the help for every list and container class in Delphi/FreePascal. The reason is pretty clear - if you have three items in the list, and the first item is at index `0`, then you have items `0, 1, 2` but a `Count` of `3`, right?

```
for i := 0 to StringList.Count - 1 do  // TStringList

for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do        // TList

for i := 0 to StringGrid1.ColCount do  // TStringGrid
```

The alternative isn't as clear (and to me is worse to type):

```
for i := 0 to Pred(StringList.Count) do
```

Dynamic arrays start at index `0` as well.

```
var
  IntArray: array of Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(IntArray, 10);
  for i := Low(IntArray) to High(IntArray) do  // loop is 0..9
    //
end;
```

The only things that aren't `0` based in FPC/Delphi are string types, which start at `1`, and non-dynamic arrays (ones that are declared with a fixed size in code), which can start at almost any index you want. For instance, this is perfectly legal:

```
var
  IntArray: array[-10..10] of Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(IntArray) to High(IntArray) do // loop is -10..10
    //
end;
```

Just as an aside, any time you do anything in your loop that will reduce the number of items in your list, you should iterate backwards:

```
for i := List.Count - 1 downto 0 do
```

Otherwise, you'll iterate beyond the end of the list, because the `Count` is only evaluated at the time the loop starts.

Comment: If arrays in Pascal start at 1, then I wonder why they'd make StringLists and such start at 0...

Comment: If you're talking about non-dynamic arrays, they can start with anything you want. `aValues: array[-10..0] of Integer;` is perfectly good Pascal, and the first index is `aValues[-10]`. Dynamic arrays (that can be resized at runtime) always start at index `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Weird, I always figured you were supposed to start them at 1... Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @SuperDisk: See my edit. I've added information about other types (such as arrays) that are zero-based in Pascal. :-)

Comment: succ and pred are only logical if you first read a textbook about pascal. succ and pred work for all ordinal types (of which integers are only a subset).

Answer (score 0):

Omg. That's because in cycle from 0 to Self.EventQueue.Count you iterate through  Self.EventQueue.Count + 1 items.

Comment: I know, but my question is why they'd design it like this so that you have to subtract 1 yourself.

Comment: That's not they designed it, that's how it works. From 0 to Count there are Count + 1 objects. That's basic math.

Comment: They started counting from zero in Delphi because the winapi did. In TP and other classic pascal code and textbooks, most arrays typically started with 1. IOW it is an imported folly. This was later reinforced when dynamic arrays were introduced.

Comment: The problem is not in counting from 0 or 1. The fact is that counting from 0 to Count there are Count + 1 objects.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere to use

```
for I := 1 to Self.EventQueue.Count do
  Dispose(Self.EventQueue[I-1]);
```

That way it is clear that nothing happens if the count is zero and the correction of the index happens at the place where it matters